# Using native pointers in F# with WritableBitmap

Tags: f#, native-code

**Hello**

I am trying to use `WritableBitmap.BackBuffer` as used in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx), see the section examples.
What I am trying to do really is write an `int[]` into a space a `nativeint` points to.

To be able to write from int [] to some memory I started from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650067/does-f-have-equivalent-syntax-to-cs-unsafe-block/3653689#3653689) on SO. 
[`Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop.NativePtr.write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370374.aspx) seems to be a good function to use to write.

After trying and reading a bit **two** questions arises.

1. `WritableBitmap.BackBuffer` has the type nativeint, how to convert to nativeptr that `NativePter.write` wants?
2. It seems that I can only write one `int` at a time but I want to write a whole `int []`.

I admit that I am in deep water but it is in the deep water you learn to swim :)

*Thank in advance*
Gorgen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the `NativePtr.write` function can be only used to write single value at a time, so if you want to copy an array, you'll have to use a `for` loop.

An easier option may be to use the `Marshal.Copy` method ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146629.aspx)) which takes a source array (there are overloads for arrays containing elements of various types) and `intptr` as the destination.

Something like this should work:

```
let imageData = [| ... |] // generate one dimensional array with image data
writeableBitmap.Lock()

let buffer = writeableBitmap.BackBuffer
Marshal.Copy(imageData, 0, buffer, imageData.Length)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think Tomas's suggested approach makes sense.  However, to answer your first question, you can convert a `nativeint` to a `nativeptr` using the `NativeInterop.NativePtr.ofNativeInt` function.